# Problem with getting AJAX to work

Tags: javascript, ajax

Having some problems with getting some ajax script to work.
Using this as the html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts\main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\mainStyle.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="onloadHandler();">
        <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:#ddd">
            Sorry, your browser does not support the canvas element.
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script:

```
function onloadHandler()
{   
    canvasItem = document.getElementById('canvas');

    canvasItem.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownEventHandler, false);
    canvasItem.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveEventHandler, false);

    callService("http://www.xul.fr/somefile.xml");
    //  callService("http://allcodecorner.com/index.html");
//  callService("http://stackoverflow.com");
//  callService("http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_info.txt");
    setTimeout("redraw()", 5);
}

function callService(serviceName)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 0)
        {
            alert('not initialized');
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1)
        {
            alert('connection established');
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 3)
        {
            alert('processing request');
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            alert('ready!');
        }

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } else {
                alert('Failed: ' + xmlhttp.responseText + ", status: " + xmlhttp.status);
            }
        }
    }
    alert(serviceName);
    xmlhttp.open("POST",serviceName,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

No matter what address I put in, I get the messages
'connection established'
'ready'
'Failed: , status: 0'.

I've tried on firefox and chrome, have tried running it locally and hosted, nothing seems to work. I always get a readyState of 4 and status of 0.
Any ideas? I've tried multiple sites to connect to, same thing every time.
Have also tried with GET, setting some headers, same result. Pretty much tried every example I could find, with no luck

Comment: Oh man, I was _sure_ I tried it with a local file. Just re-tried it then, worked fine. Thanks :). Chuck your comment as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: done! The usual workaround is a server-side proxy that fetches the content for you and feeds it to your JS in a local context.

Comment: I think your hitting the cross-domain protection. You can't use XHR to talk to other domains

Comment: Yep, should be no worries - intending to access a file on the same host, was just running this locally for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to make an Ajax request to a remote location, which is impossible due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Not sure whether there's a fix: If you control the remote location, you can make it send JSONP instead. If that's not possible, you're going to have to use a server-side proxy.